# Problem adding GeoServer layer to map in openlayers after cross-layer filtering

Tags: openlayers, wms

I have queried 2 layers `(one polygon & one polyline)` using `CQL_FILTER` which I want to add to map, but it is not giving the results similar to the ones obtained from URL.

`"http://localhost:8585/geoserver/aasdagrometgis/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&LAYERS=aasdagrometgis:INDIA_DIST_717_GCS,aasdagrometgis:railway_shapefile&CQL_FILTER=CROSSES(geometry, collectGeometries(queryCollection('railway_shapefile', 'geometry', 'FROM=''DELHI'' AND TO=''AMBALA''')));FROM='DELHI' AND TO='AMBALA'&bbox=68.18624877929688%2C6.755565643310547%2C97.41529846191406%2C37.07667922973633&width=740&height=768&srs=EPSG%3A4326&styles=&format=application/openlayers"`

If I parse/paste and run the URL in browser then I get the desired result as

[image]

but I am unable to fetch the same WMS `with map.addLayer();`

and the result is different

`1.) getting only polyline vector layer`

`2.) no polygon vector layer along it`

`3.) and multiple/all the polylines appear, instead of the queried one`

The JS is as follows

```
      var quaried_layer_source = new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8585/geoserver/aasdagrometgis/wms',
        params: { "LAYERS": "aasdagrometgis:India_state_boundary,aasdagrometgis:railway_shapefile", "tiled": true },
        serverType: "geoserver",
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
        format:  "application/openlayers",
        CQL_FILTER: "CROSSES(geometry,collectGeometries(queryCollection('railway_shapefile','geometry','FROM=''DELHI'' AND TO=''AMBALA''')));FROM='DELHI' AND TO='AMBALA",
        transparent: true,
        version: "1.1.0",
        request: "GetMap&LAYERS"
      })
      var quaried_layer_WMS = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: quaried_layer_source,
        opacity: 1.0,
        zIndex: 5,
        visible: true,
        title: "quaried_layer_WMS"
      })
```

Current output being returned is

[image]
so

How to add the CQL_FILTERed layer to the map having cross-layer filtering?

Comment: You are not specifying cross origin access for the TileWMS and unless it is to avoid tainted canvas you do not need it.  If you are making a valid request and the server is returning an image there should be no problem.  You should not be getting a text/html MIME type response unless there was an error.  What do you get if you copy and paste the urls in the error messages?

Comment: some blank images (broken tiles probably) @Mike

Comment: You would add `crossOrigin: 'anonymous'`, in the ol.source.TileWMS options (but you can load images without CORS, you only need it if you intend to print maps or make FeatureInfo requests)

Comment: Thanks @Mike, The CORB error ain't appearing now, However the map is still not being fetched with map.addLayer(quaried_layer_WMS);

Comment: Actually there are 2 different vector layers in URL ```aasdagrometgis:India_state_boundary``` & ```aasdagrometgis:railway_shapefile```whose features are merged. Is there some issue with the syntax?

Comment: Coz when I am using URL in chrome ```http://localhost:8585/geoserver/aasdagrometgis/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&LAYERS=aasdagrometgis:INDIA_DIST_717_GCS,aasdagrometgis:railway_shapefile&CQL_FILTER=CROSSES(geometry, collectGeometries(queryCollection('railway_shapefile', 'geometry', 'FROM=''DELHI'' AND TO=''AMBALA''')));FROM='DELHI' AND TO='AMBALA'&bbox=68.18624877929688%2C6.755565643310547%2C97.41529846191406%2C37.07667922973633&width=740&height=768&srs=EPSG%3A4326&styles=&format=application/openlayers``` it is returning vector layer as in the figure above. So URL is working

Comment: Layers in the list should be separated by commas, and probably best not to include any extra spaces `"aasdagrometgis:India_state_boundary,aasdagrometgis:railway_shapefile"`